# Can't return from activity started from CordovaPlugin

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

My app starts an activity from a plugin. The activity has to start, there's no other way around it. It then gathers some data and sends it back to the plugin.

Everything works perfect, I start the activitywith

```
this.cordova.startActivityForResults((CordovaPlugin)this,i,0);
```

and finish it with `finish();` after returning some data via intent...

Everything works, the activity sends the data, the plugin receives the data, but then the whole app just closes... I cant return from the called activity back to the main one. The same thing happens when I press "back" in the called activity.

Any ideas?